# Google Maps API v3: Can I create Place Autocomplete in combobox using ExtJS 4.2?

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, extjs, google-maps-api-3

I have search this over on google, but no luck finding the solution. I have read [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) documentation but it just using pure javascript.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20564541/google-places-auto-complete-in-extjs4) from older post created by @Ram, but the answer didn't solve my problem, because I think maybe there's other ideas more tricky way that I don't reach it now from my current knowledge.

I have tried using ajax from php to retrieve predictions and to throw away that limitation, this's my php code in c_places.php :

```
function getPlaces(){
        $address = urlencode($this->input->post('place'));
        $request = file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" . $address . "&sensor=false");
        // $json = json_decode($request, true);
        echo $request;
    }
```

this's my ajax call :

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'c_places/getPlaces',
    params: {
        "place" : someplace
    },
    success: function(response, opts) {
        var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
        console.dir(obj);
    },
    failure: function(response, opts) {
        console.info('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
    }
});
```

the ajax return a json obj from googleapis, but i don't know how to put this json to the data.store of combobox, Because this call dynamically from user when typing location. So if I put the Ext.data.store in the beginning before combobox, the combobox only show the original store, not from user when typing location. But, before you try this url : `http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="address"&sensor=false`

sometimes this url give me a json output, but sometimes give me error "Server not found". I don't know why, until i post this the url show me the error, but this's not a problem, because i've another trick to get the json.

My problem is :
1. Is there a way to load json store dynamically from combobox it self using keyup listener to call my ajax ? i mean, not using other combobox to trigger load from another combobox.
2. Is there a way to create this place autocomplete in using ExtJS 4.2? or Other ideas to solve this?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Please correct me, if my question didn't focus the problem or my question is too broad or unclear problem statement. I'll gladly edit my post to give more detail.

Comment: This is simple, have a look at the Sencha example called "live Search" http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/form/forum-search.html

Comment: Ihave take a look at sencha live search before, but i didn' get some enlighment, not yet. may be you can help me with your logic how to use that to create autocomplete ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok have a look at this code below, here were are just using a local fixed data source but in your example you would point this at your `c_places.php` with an appropriate proxy.  Since in the example there data source is fixed it is always returning the same data but in your instance you'd have to check for the typed value.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
        addressModel = Ext.define("Addresses", {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            proxy: {
                type: 'jsonp',
                url: 'https://jsonp.nodejitsu.com',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'results',
                    totalProperty: 'totalCount'
                }
            },

            fields: ['formatted_address']
        });

        var ds = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            model: 'Addresses'
        });


        var panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            title: 'Search the Addresses',
            width: 600,
            bodyPadding: 10,
            layout: 'anchor',

            items: [{
                xtype: 'combo',
                store: ds,
                displayField: 'title',
                typeAhead: false,
                hideLabel: true,
                hideTrigger: true,
                anchor: '100%',
                enableKeyEvents: true,

                listConfig: {
                    loadingText: 'Searching...',
                    emptyText: 'No matching posts found.',

                    // Custom rendering template for each item
                    getInnerTpl: function() {
                        return '<div class="search-item">{formatted_address}</div>';
                    }
                },

                // override default onSelect to do redirect
                listeners: {
                    select: function(combo, selection) {
                        var address = selection[0];
                        if (address) {
                            alert('you picked ' + address.data.formatted_address);
                        }
                    },
                    keyup: function(combo) {
                        queryString = combo.getValue();
                        console.log(queryString);
                        console.log(addressModel);
                        addressModel.getProxy().setExtraParam('url', 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + queryString + '&sensor=false');
                    }
                }
            }, {
                xtype: 'component',
                style: 'margin-top:10px',
                html: 'Live search requires a minimum of 4 characters.'
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Demo: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/g70

Comment: Thanks, for taking time to create a demo. I've take a look your demo code bro @Rob-Schmuecker, i want to ask you about "how if my search the address return responses when i typing the addresses ?" I mean, originally i don't have a data at the beginning but when user input an address, my combobox dynamically build a store when i begin typing the address, and that store supply the combobox. Because I know you know that using place prediction depend on googleapis json that we requested. so if we requested "city" the json return about city and the url request follow user input ex "city".

Comment: at last, when user typing location it'll supply the store to provide prediction to the combobox. Is there a way to do that ?
Because that's a logic that I've in my head. May I too compicated, please guide me to the simplest way to reach that.

Comment: Not really too clear on what exactly you mean.  There are plenty of people who consult on this for a fee to get you exactly what you want.  Stackoverflow is not for such specific tasks as that.  We're not here to do your work for you but rather help point you in the right direction and if there's a specific issue make a question about that rather than one long one asking people to basically do your project spec.

Comment: I'm sorry, not to meant it. But, I didn't ask for to do my work. Just a little hint, the logic to implement that. I'm very appreciate for your answer and your snippet code. Once again I don't mean it, as you said i just need a point to the right direction.

Comment: OK - I have updated the answer and the demo.  Now any query you do will show you returned results from the API via a proxy

Comment: That's cool bro @Rob-Schmuecker, this is "addressModel.getProxy().setExtraParam('url', 'https://jsonp.nodejitsu.com/?url=http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + queryString + '&sensor=false');"

That's a code exactly I search it for... Thanks, you saved me a lot...

Comment: @EkoJunaidiSalam Sorry I updated the code, it's meant to just be `addressModel.getProxy().setExtraParam('url', 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + queryString + '&sensor=false');`

Comment: Yesss... I'm very stupid not to remember using extraParam in my ajax to supply dynamically the data store url... You save me bro...

Answer (score 1):

Why not instead of use the sencha combobox, use a simple text input as suggest the google api autocomplete documentation. (I first tried with a just common textfield but it didn't work) 
Then declare a component with html as the following example, and then assign the render:

```
xtype: 'component',
html: '<div> <input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50"> </div>',
listeners: {
    render: function () {
        var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, { types: ['geocode'] });
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', this.fillInAddress);
    },
```

Now if you want to use this component inside a Panel, there are conflicts with Sencha Styles. So you need to add in html file declaration of google api. ( I tried adding to my css file but it doesn't work either )
The google autocomplete dynamic style:

```
    <style type="text/css">
        .pac-container {
            z-index: 100000 !important;
        }
    </style>
```

[image: Autocomplete in a Panel]